# Why does RefCell:borrow_mut result in a BorrowMutError when used on both sides of a short-circuiting boolean AND (&&)?

Tags: rust, refcell

I wrote this code for the leetcode [same tree problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}

struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn is_same_tree(
        p: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
        q: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    ) -> bool {
        match (p, q) {
            (None, None) => true,
            (Some(p), Some(q)) if p.borrow().val == q.borrow().val => {
                // this line won't work, it will cause BorrowMutError at runtime
                // but the `a & b` version works
                return (Self::is_same_tree(
                    p.borrow_mut().left.take(),
                    q.borrow_mut().left.take(),
                )) && (Self::is_same_tree(
                    p.borrow_mut().right.take(),
                    q.borrow_mut().right.take(),
                ));

                let a = Self::is_same_tree(p.borrow_mut().left.take(), q.borrow_mut().left.take());
                let b =
                    Self::is_same_tree(p.borrow_mut().right.take(), q.borrow_mut().right.take());
                a && b
            }
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode {
        val: 1,
        left: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(2)))),
        right: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3)))),
    })));
    let q = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode {
        val: 1,
        left: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(2)))),
        right: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3)))),
    })));

    println!("{:?}", Solution::is_same_tree(p, q));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab936536db1d7346f571ae81b5f671da)

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:39:23
```

I think `&&` is a short-circuit operator which means the two expressions won't exist at the same time, so two mutable references should not exist at the same time.

Comment: By inferring the missing pieces, I got to [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af603fc9f53ca8f606cc23397fe17955), which actually compiles. The problem cannot be reproduced. Are you perchance using an old version of the compiler?

Comment: @E_net4ishere I'm using 1.49.0-nightly. btw I have updated my question, you can try it on the Rust Playground.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the example! I'd guess the rust compiler considers whole expressions at once when executing destructors for the mutable handles. You can work around this and still maintain short-circuiting by pulling just the left side of the `&&` into a prior declaration.

Comment: [A minimized example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23a94854b302c21f98a1caa64cbc0a39)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimized example:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let x = RefCell::new(true);
    *x.borrow_mut() && *x.borrow_mut();
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:8:27
```

When you call [`RefCell::borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut), a temporary value of type [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html) is returned. From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.47.0/reference/expressions.html#temporaries):

> The drop scope of the temporary is usually the end of the enclosing statement.

And [in expanded detail](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.47.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes):

> Apart from lifetime extension, the temporary scope of an expression is
> the smallest scope that contains the expression and is for one of the
> following:
>
> - The entire function body.
> - A statement.
> - The body of a `if`, `while` or `loop` expression.
> - The `else` block of an `if` expression.
> - The condition expression of an `if` or `while` expression, or a `match` guard.
> - The expression for a match arm.
> - The second operand of a [lazy boolean expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.47.0/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#lazy-boolean-operators).

The failing code would look something like this if it were expanded:

```rust
{
    let t1 = x.borrow_mut();

    *t1 && {
        let t2 = x.borrow_mut();
        *t2
    }
}
```

This shows how the double borrow occurs.

As you've already noticed, you can work around this by declaring a variable ahead-of-time. This preserves the short-circuit nature:

```rust
let a = *x.borrow_mut();
a && *x.borrow_mut();
```

Comment: Thank you. Does "The second operand of a lazy boolean expression." mean that in `a & b`, `a` will be dropped after b has been evaluated, and in `a & b & c = (a & b) & c`, a and be will be dropped before evaluating `c`. so this explains this example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=280ad95988dbdaa89fd67afcfb26d182

Comment: Yes. In my expanded code, you can see that as the nested `{}` block containing `t2`. *in `a & b`* — `&` is **not** lazy / short-circuiting. Only `&&` is.

Comment: sorry. I just get up, my mind is in a mess. I indeed mean `&&` and I cannot edit my comment after 5min. It should be: Does "The second operand of a lazy boolean expression." mean that in `a && b`, `a` will be dropped after `b` has been evaluated, and in `a && b && c = (a && b) && c`, `a` and `b` will be dropped before evaluating `c`. so this explains this example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=280ad95988dbdaa89fd67afcfb26d182